# AddressBook not working in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, xcode7-beta4

Recently I have downloaded Xcode beta4 for giving support to iOS 9 in myApp.Now the address book is not working its show blank screen when I select a contact, with following logs.

plugin com.apple.MobileAddressBook.ContactsViewService interrupted
plugin com.apple.MobileAddressBook.ContactsViewService invalidated

I have implemented all major delegate of ABPeoplePicker and put break points its not going in any of them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**
This issue has been solved by Apple since Xcode 7 GM , I have confirmed that it works.

ABPeoplePickerNavigationController no longer works on iOS9,

Apple created new library/framework for Contacts in iOS9 ( https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html )

even if application is compiled/built with older Xcode (6) it still behaves like that, in Beta 2 it crashed , in beta 3 it shows black screen,

Apples sample project ( https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/PeoplePicker/Introduction/Intro.html ) also has the same issue/behavior.

I have opened an issue at bugreport.apple.com ( id - 22001958 ) , saying that it should at least behave like older iOS versions

Comment: Its still giving same error in xCode7 GM with Swift. Do you have any idea why this is happening? also after targeting it for iOS 8 it should work properly but it gives error for iOS 8 and iOS 9 as well.

Comment: try downloading the latest Xcode, this should be resolved